# Why does GParted make my flash disk bootable? If not malware then what?

Tags: linux, security, mbr, gparted

I did `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda` where `/dev/sda` is my flash disk. `/dev/sda` was all zeros after this. Then I created a partition table with GParted on the flash disk. I made no other changes. Now this is the output of `sudo dd if=/dev/sda bs=512 count=1|hexdump -C`:

```
00000000  fa b8 00 10 8e d0 bc 00  b0 b8 00 00 8e d8 8e c0  |................|
00000010  fb be 00 7c bf 00 06 b9  00 02 f3 a4 ea 21 06 00  |...|.........!..|
00000020  00 be be 07 38 04 75 0b  83 c6 10 81 fe fe 07 75  |....8.u........u|
00000030  f3 eb 16 b4 02 b0 01 bb  00 7c b2 80 8a 74 01 8b  |.........|...t..|
00000040  4c 02 cd 13 ea 00 7c 00  00 eb fe 00 00 00 00 00  |L.....|.........|
00000050  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000001b0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  fd 5c ba 4c 00 00 00 00  |.........\.L....|
000001c0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000001f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 55 aa  |..............U.|
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
512 bytes (512 B) copied, 0.00183447 s, 279 kB/s
00000200
```

I tried it twice. My question is why did this happen. As I understand it the partition table starts after the 446th byte and there's no reason for the `55 aa` signature to be there.

What could it be if not malware?

Answer (score 2):

GParted always writes the 55AA signature to the MBR even if it is not strictly needed. (As you already mentioned it is only required for a BOOTABLE MBR.)

The reason lies in historical compatibility reasons.
Some systems with badly implemented MBR processing code flatly consider a MBR invalid if it doesn't have the signature.
To prevent this problem GParted (and most other software that can create a MBR) will put dummy/safe bootloader code in the MBR and give it the "Bootable disk" signature.